# Bootstrap 4.1.2: Looking to add Bootstrap 4.1.2 to my project,Using a package manager npm?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, npm, stylesheet

- Looking to add Bootstrap 4.1.2 to my project,Using a package manager npm? **

**note: i want that locally not using Use BootstrapCDN as below:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

i will try add to my project using the below two line:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../SCSS/custom.scss">
```

but i get the below error on my console page:

[image: error on my console page]

please anyone can help me on that error ....

Comment: You should provide more detail such as what kind of project you are trying to develop using npm? Whether it's node js, Angular etc?

Comment: Using node.js express .. and also this version of bootstrap have scss variable

Answer (score 0):

To add bootstrap to a nodejs project, you would do the following:

Open command window.
Navigate to your project's root folder.
Type:

npm install --save bootstrap

After installation, you can add it to your nodejs file, like so:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(_dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(_dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')))
```